# Adding new feature in address book in android

Tags: android, contacts

Hi is it possible to add new feature in existing address book??

What i am trying to do is i want to add my application shortcut just like there is a shortcut for sms into every contact, whenever user opens any contact he can see my application option there, he taps to it and my application will launch with that contact information is it possible?

We have options like link to facebook, flicker in the contact list how they have implemented this?? can i create similar thing??

Can i do it in 1.6 or any higher version has support??